# Implementing JQuery DataTables and RowGrouping in WAMP Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I am implementing the dataTable and rowGrouping in a wamp server. The code is from
     [this jjsfiddle site](http://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/4Rkb3/36/)

But am not able to get both the dataTable and rowGrouping working as in the jsfiddle site.

This is the file structure.

```html
expandRows    
         |   
         epandTables.html 
         | 
         css
            |
            styles.css
           |
           dataTables.css // dataTable css library file
           |
        scripts
               |
                rowToggle.js
               |
               rowGroupings
               |
               dataTables.js //datatables pluggin
               |
               jquery-1.12.1.min.js
```

The html code is presented below.

```html
          

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <title>Table Project</title> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dataRows.css"> 
 <script src="scripts/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/rowtoggle.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/rowGrouping.js"></script>
  
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="demo">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rendering engine</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine</th>
            <th>CSS</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd_gradeX" id="2">
            <td class="read_only">Trident</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 4.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center">4</td>

            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeC" id="4">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center">5</td>

            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeA" id="5">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center">5.5</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeA" id="1">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td class="read_only">Internet Explorer 6</td>
            <td>Win 98+</td>
            <td class="center">6</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeA" id="5">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 7</td>
            <td class="read_only">Win XP SP2+</td>
            <td class="center">7</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeA" id="1">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>AOL browser (AOL desktop)</td>
            <td>Win XP</td>
            <td class="center">6</td>

            <td class="center read_only">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeA" id="5">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 1.0</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.7</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeA" id="1">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 1.5</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeA" id="5">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 2.0</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeA" id="1">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 3.0</td>
            <td>Win 2k+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td class="center">1.9</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeA" id="5">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Camino 1.0</td>
            <td>OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeA" id="1">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Camino 1.5</td>
            <td>OSX.3+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeA" id="5">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape 7.2</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2</td>
            <td class="center">1.7</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeA" id="1">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape Browser 8</td>
            <td>Win 98SE+</td>
            <td class="center">1.7</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeA" id="5">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape Navigator 9</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeA" id="1">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeA" id="5">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.1</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.1</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeA" id="1">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.2</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.2</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeA" id="5">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.3</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.3</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeA" id="1">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.4</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.4</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeA" id="5">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.5</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeA" id="1">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.6</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.6</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeA" id="5">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.7</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.7</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeA" id="1">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.8</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeA" id="5">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Seamonkey 1.1</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeA" id="1">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Epiphany 2.20</td>
            <td>Gnome</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeA" id="5">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 1.2</td>
            <td>OSX.3</td>
            <td class="center">125.5</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeA" id="1">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 1.3</td>
            <td>OSX.3</td>
            <td class="center">312.8</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeA" id="5">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 2.0</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td class="center">419.3</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeA" id="1">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 3.0</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td class="center">522.1</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeA" id="5">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>OmniWeb 5.5</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td class="center">420</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeA" id="1">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>iPod Touch / iPhone</td>
            <td>iPod</td>
            <td class="center">420.1</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeA" id="5">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>S60</td>
            <td>S60</td>
            <td class="center">413</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeA" id="1">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 7.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeA" id="5">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 7.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeA" id="1">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 8.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeA" id="5">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 8.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeA" id="1">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeA" id="5">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.2</td>
            <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeA" id="1">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.5</td>
            <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeA" id="5">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera for Wii</td>
            <td>Wii</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeA" id="1">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Nokia N800</td>
            <td>N800</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>

            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeA" id="5">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Nintendo DS browser</td>
            <td>Nintendo DS</td>
            <td class="center">8.5</td>

            <td class="center">C/A<sup>1</sup></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeC" id="4">
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.1</td>
            <td>KDE 3.1</td>

            <td class="center">3.1</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeA" id="5">
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.3</td>
            <td>KDE 3.3</td>

            <td class="center">3.3</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeA" id="1">
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.5</td>
            <td>KDE 3.5</td>

            <td class="center">3.5</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeX" id="2">
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 4.5</td>
            <td>Mac OS 8-9</td>

            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeC" id="4">
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.1</td>
            <td>Mac OS 7.6-9</td>

            <td class="center">1</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeC" id="3">
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.2</td>
            <td>Mac OS 8-X</td>

            <td class="center">1</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeA" id="1">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>NetFront 3.1</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>

            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeA" id="5">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>NetFront 3.4</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>

            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeX" id="11">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Dillo 0.8</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>

            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeX" id="2">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Links</td>
            <td>Text only</td>

            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeX" id="11">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Lynx</td>
            <td>Text only</td>

            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeC" id="3">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>IE Mobile</td>
            <td>Windows Mobile 6</td>

            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even_gradeC" id="4">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>PSP browser</td>
            <td>PSP</td>

            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeU" id="10">
            <td>All Other browsers</td>
            <td>All others</td>
            <td>-</td>

            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">U</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd_gradeU" id="11">
            <td>All Other browsers</td>
            <td>Unknown</td>
            <td>-</td>

            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">U</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>


</body> 
</html>
```

This code is from the rowToggle.js file

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bJQueryUI": true
    }).rowGrouping({
        bExpandableGrouping: true,
        bExpandSingleGroup: false,
        iExpandGroupOffset: -1,
        asExpandedGroups: [""]
    });
});
```

This is from styles.css

```css
tr:hover th, tr:hover td {
    background-color:#ebebeb;
    background-image:none;
}
td {
    height:26px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 20px !important;
    text-align:left;
    border-bottom:1px solid #d0d0d0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    color:#555555;
    background-color:#ffffff;

}
td.group {
    background-color: #d5eafd !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #94bafd;
    border-top: 1px solid #94bafd;
}
td.expanded-group {
    background: url("http://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/media/images/minus.jpg") no-repeat scroll left center transparent;
}
tr:hover td.expanded-group {
    background: url("http://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/media/images/minus.jpg") no-repeat scroll left center #c0e1ff !important;
}

td.collapsed-group {
    background: url("http://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/media/images/plus.jpg") no-repeat scroll left center transparent;
}
tr:hover td.collapsed-group {
    background: url("http://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/media/images/plus.jpg") no-repeat scroll left center #c0e1ff !important;
}
.DataTables_sort_wrapper span{
    float: right;
}
```